# object doesn't support this action in IE6 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, internet-explorer-6

For some reason the following line of javascript is giving me an error `object doesn't support this action` in IE6:

```
item = ui.item.get(0);
```

Any ideas? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Does `item = ui.item[0];` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui.item is a single DOM element.  No need for the get() call.

Answer (score 8):

Internet Explorer hates it when you use the word "item" as variable name. Change it to something else.

Comment: This was my problem as well. Very frustrating. Saw this answer and got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that ui is null? Or that ui.item is null?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 6 doesn't like it when you use "start" as a function name. That fixed it for me. Perhaps someone knows a list of these reserved words? I think I've also noticed that a DOM element id "submit" gives similar problems, but that's a while ago, I might misremember that. Anyway...

Broken code (in IE6 anyway):

```
<input type=button value=Start onclick="start();">
<script> function start(){ /*Do whatever*/ } </script>
```

Working code:

```
<input type=button value=Start onclick="start2();">
<script> function start2(){ /*Do whatever*/ } </script>
```

Thanks to @Mike's answer for hinting at this by saying that the word "item" was not allowed to be used as variable. Turns out to be the same for more words.